# Why it's needed to retrieve Redux state via getState() function and not just .state property, as in React components

Tags: reactjs, redux

**React Components api:**
SETTER: .setState()
GETTER: .state

**Redux api:**
SETTER: In reducers
GETTER: .getState()

Why is not state in Redux accessible just through `.state`?

Answer (score 2):

Redux handles the state as a private variable instead of an exposed property.

As a result, it is impossible to shoot yourself in the foot by doing something like <s>`store.state.counter = 43`</s>* `store.state = newState`. The only way to change the state is the recommended one - by dispatching actions.

***Update**
Well I guess you could as well shoot yourself in the foot with `store.getState().counter = 43`. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/4b63737c7faceb62dd2f4ff8be3e707bf66d6993/src/createStore.js) it seems more like the getter syntax was just more convenient from the development point of view, as now there is no need to keep any public `store.state` property up to date. You can do whatever you want with the `getState` function and it will just work regardless of the context.

Comment: > "it is impossible to shoot yourself in the foot" Don't you know if this is the reason for being private or just consequence?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure, but I guess this is the reason. Redux [source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/src) is very easy to read and as the getState function is just `function getState() { return currentState; }` I don't see any *technical* reason why it couldn't be a public property instead. [Some source code comments](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L16) seem to emphasize the private nature of the state too.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the syntax provided by the API, you should rarely need to access the entire state of your Redux store using `.getState()`, if at all.  You should be using [the official React bindings for Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to supply state to your components.

[Here's the official documentation for using React with Redux.](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

Comment: I was more interested in reasoning behind this API design and it's difference to React